# Can anything remove fingerprints from your fingers?

Tags: biology, criminology

Here's where it gets interesting; I don't mean erase them from an object, I mean from your fingers directly.  Some people claim there is a way to do it, some people claim it's impossible.

I have a friend (no, really, she exists, I swear) who is attempting to write a novel, and for once, someone turned to a skeptic in an attempt to get the science right.

She's been apparently scouring sites like [this](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081020100905AAenEAb) in an attempt to find a plausible method, presumably because there aren't many places to go for hard facts on this topic.

Of course, there's very little (I couldn't find any) scientific study published on this topic, and many proposed solutions to the problem seem to be quite painful, bloody, and ultimately futile.

It's also probably safe to assume the people offering advice via message boards on this particular topic are at best speculating, haven't actually had any practical or relevent experience, and are most likely basing claims on exaggerated or fictional accounts rather than demonstrable evidence.(Interestingly, I kept running across stories involving John Dillinger attempting this which may or may not be true). However, without the data, there's obviously no way for me to say for sure.

Even though none of them sound like advice I would be willing to take, nor do they come from credible sources, some suggestions so far have been...

- **[Cut them off](http://www.scribd.com/doc/18551934/Changing-Your-Fingerprints)** - (not your fingers, just your fingerprints) Apparently this does
  not work that well, is obviously
  painful and could possibly make
  fingerprints more distinctive
  according to some.
- **[Using a corrosive substance](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Can_acid_or_surgery_successfully_remove_your_fingerprints)** - Does
  not seem to yield acceptable results,
  as much like cutting them off, they
  will regrow.
- **[Burning them off](http://www.ask.com/questions-about/How-to-Burn-off-Your-Fingerprints)** - This has received
  some questionable support, but many
  seem to think they will grow back.
- **[Rubbing them off](http://onin.com/fp/wwwbd/messages/4/2029.html?1240958462)** - some claim this
  smooths them out, and is certainly not as gory but they quickly
  return to normal.
- **[Surgical removal](http://www.abajournal.com/news/article/more_criminals_using_acid_surgery_and_burning_to_alter_fingerprints/)** - I ran across some
  unverifiable claims about this
  method.
- And at least [one strange method
  involving a pineapple](http://www.rotteneggsx.com/r3/show/se/179977.html) which only
  attempts to alter them, not remove
  them entirely.

I keep thinking that there's something I'm missing here.

- **Have any of those methods ever been
  proven to be successful?**
- **Has anyone ever successfully had
  his/her fingerprints erased
  successfully by any method?**
- **Is there a scientifically valid way
  to do it, even if it's extremely
  improbable?**

Or is this all just spy-movie stuff with no hard science behind it?

Comment: WHY would one want to do it if wearing cellophane or other plastic film taped/glued to fingertips gets the exact same effect with no dramatics?

Comment: @DVK, Why not gloves, and skip the hassle of applying tape to yourself? (Actually, when I was a kid, I heard of people having their fingerprints picked up through latex gloves. As an adult, that sounds awfully like a story a cop might invent to persuade someone to confess.)

Comment: @DVK @Odd before I posted this I realized, the why is sort of immaterial, it's the how which seems more interesting (and more appropriate here). Although personally, I imagine something more like having to get fingerprinted at a police station or scanned at an airport or something, where they won't exactly let you wear gloves. I know, that opens a whole can of worms.

Comment: Anecdotal: Recently in Germany new ID-cards were introduced with fingerprints. To prevent fingerprints being taken, different techniques were discussed. One is to use superglue, but it will only work temporary and last for some days or weeks. [Link in german language] (http://www.computerwoche.de/security/1883805/)

Comment: @Monkey, I imagine that turning up at a police station without *any* fingerprints is likely to attract even more attention!

Comment: I'm sure I heard of a case where a construction worker only had partial fingerprints because of the chemicals he had been handling in his daily work which made it very hard for the police to identify him.  Pineapples are also supposed to contain something that removes fingerprints causing pineapple pickers to be fingerprintless.

In both cases the skin will regrow after enough time so it is not a permentant removal.  I have not done any research to get sources hence not an answer but a comment.

Comment: Lime burns the skin, effectively, so would be a good temp measure as they would come back eventually.  Any building work, ground work and construction, would effectvely buff them off as well.  There are many ways you can lose the print temporarily, but I am guessing to do this permenently, you'd have to have surgery.

Comment: Don't forget that, if you know you're not going to want to leave your fingerprints for a specific occasion, you can leave somebody else's, apparently with ingredients found in the typical Japanese professor's house.  He spoofed automatic fingerprint readers.

Comment: @user unknown: The fingerprints on the new German ID-card are optional. They are mandatory however for all new passports.

Comment: [MythBusters](http://www.edutube.org/video/can-fingerprints-be-forged) forge fingerprints with latex and superglue ;)

Comment: Your 'one strange method involving a pineapple' link is broken. :(

Comment: I just watched "I (almost) got away with it." This guy guy burned off his fingerprints with acid, losing one fingertip in the process. He was still apprehended though, and a partial print remained (enough to help identify him).

Comment: This is a personal anecdote, but I accidentally cut the 1/8" of my thumb tip off last year. It grew back, but the ridges of my fingerprints around the cut-off portion are quite distorted now, with absolutely no ridges in the center portion of the scar.

Comment: I bite my cuticles and have partially lost some prints and have definite faded patches in a lot of areas. When the skin regrows it gradually flattens out.

Comment: Also, if you burned the finger tip thoroughly it would definitely erase the print.

Comment: The folks at WETA Workshop who made chainmail for the Lord of the Rings movies handle so many rough metal rings that they wore down the prints on their index and thumb fingers completely by the time they were done. They eventually returned of course.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[image: Fingerprints] <sub>[Source](http://www.fountainmagazine.com/article.php?ARTICLEID=790)</sub>

**CNN article from 2010**: **[Fingerprint mutilation on the rise, but it's practically pointless](http://articles.cnn.com/2010-07-23/justice/mutilated.fingerprints_1_mutilation-fingerprint-forensics?_s=PM:CRIME)**

> According to Stephen G. Fischer Jr., a
>   spokesman for the *FBI's Criminal
>   Justice Information Services*, **methods of
>   fingerprint mutilation can vary
>   depending on the circumstance and the
>   criminal.**
>
> "*It can go from people chewing on
>   fingers, using a knife, burning acid
>   or cigarettes. Or if
>   you have a career criminal or someone
>   who is a little more affluent, they
>   might go to a surgeon.*"
>
> While no hard data on fingerprint
>   mutilations exist, Fischer says the
>   **FBI's forensics examiners have noticed
>   the uptick over the last few years**,
>   though the reason is unclear.
>
> But **advancements in forensics
>   technology have made fingerprint
>   mutilation increasingly difficult to
>   pull off**, as even severely damaged
>   fingers will provide investigators
>   with clues.
>
> "*We can identify prints that we
>   couldn't 10 or 15 years ago. Basically, they're going
>   through all this pain and expense for
>   no reason*."

From **[Scientific American](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=lose-your-fingerprints):**

> A Singaporean **[cancer patient was
>   detained by U.S. customs](http://www.timesonline.co.uk/tol/news/uk/health/article6368231.ece) because his
>   cancer treatment had made his
>   fingerprints disappear**.
>
> As it turns out, **the drug,
>   [capecitabine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capecitabine) (brand name, *Xeloda*) had
>   given him a moderate case of something
>   known as [hand–foot syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palmar_plantar_erythrodysesthesia) (aka
>   [chemotherapy-induced acral erythema](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18394404?ordinalpos=3&itool=EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Pubmed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DefaultReportPanel.Pubmed_RVDocSum)).**
>
> **What are some other ways that fingerprints can disappear?**
>
> - **bricklayers** — who wear down ridges on their prints handling heavy, rough materials frequently
> - **people who work with lime** [calcium oxide] - because it's really basic and dissolves the top layers of the skin. The fingerprints tend to grow back over time.
> - surprisingly, **secretaries** - because they deal with paper all day. The constant handling of paper tends to wear down the ridge detail.
> - also, the [elasticity of skin decreases with age](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=anti-aging-treatment-science), so a lot of **senior citizens** have prints that are difficult to capture. The ridges get thicker; the height between the top of the ridge and the bottom of the furrow gets narrow, so there's less prominence. So if there's any pressure at all [on the scanner], the print just tends to smear.
>
> But Forensics expert [Edward Richards](http://www.law.lsu.edu/index.cfm?geaux=profiles.showbio&personnel=CF6477F7-1372-69E5-F7752289253E812B) notes:
>   
> "... ***your skin replaces at a fairly good rate, so unless you've done permanent damage to the tissue, it will regenerate***."

From **[National Geographic - Born Without Fingerprints](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2006/09/060922-fingerprints.html):**

> **Two rare and related diseases leave
>   their sufferers with no fingerprints**:
>
> - [Naegeli syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naegeli%E2%80%93Franceschetti%E2%80%93Jadassohn_syndrome)
> - [dermatopathia pigmentosa reticularis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermatopathia_pigmentosa_reticularis) (DPR).

One case of DPR is [Flight attendant Cheryl Maynard](http://abcnews.go.com/Health/story?id=2771451&page=1).

Comment: It would be interesting to see how much would the no permanent fingerprint problem make identification difficult (any studies in that area?). Back in the days when my grandmother was medical student, they brought a dead fingerprintless guy in the morgue. At the time, there weren't extensive centralized fingerprint databases in my country, but they identified him because he had no fingerprints. It turned out that the list of people who had natural fingerprints was extremely short at the time.

Comment: (Warning: conspiracy mode activated.) Could it be possible that the FBI statement (through CNN) is deliberate misinformation in order to lower the number of fingerprint mutilation and ease forensic efforts?

Comment: @ChrisR Non-zero possibility, certainly, but I'd call it highly unlikely. While the CSI shows are *painful* to watch if you're into science at all, the fact that forensic science has made massive strides over the past few decades isn't really disputed.

Comment: Sounds to me that prints of a mutilated finger are even more distinctive than normal fingerprint.

Answer (score 11):

This is largely anecdotal, but it is certainly possible to **temporarily** *obscure* one's fingerprints by simply coating one's fingerprints using glue, or a similar liquid adhesive.

I've had this happen to me while working with cyanoacrylate adhesives, more commonly known as superglue. Basically, the adhesive forms a film over the fingertip, and fills the grooves, then cures. The end result is a smooth surface on your fingertip.

[Wikipedia says:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanoacrylate)

> Some rock climbers use cyanoacrylate to repair damage to the skin on their fingertips.[8][9] Similarly, stringed-instrument players can form protective finger caps (in addition to calluses) with cyanoacrylates.

Additionally,

> Thin CA glue also has application in woodworking. It can be used as a fast drying, glossy finish.

Which is exactly what happens if you get it on your skin.

Fortunately (or unfortunately, depending on why you are trying to obscure your fingertips), getting CA glue on your skin is not permanent. It simply flakes off along with the outer layer of skin, as your epidermis naturally replaces itself.

Answer (score 4):

According to a 2012 [Cracked article](http://www.cracked.com/article_19779_5-supposedly-badass-criminals-caught-in-embarrassing-ways_p2.html), Robert Phillips succeeded with a skin graft.

> Phillips simply convinced a doctor to graft skin from his abdomen and surgically sew it where his fingerprints were. Just like that, Phillips went down in history as the only known successful case of someone permanently blanking out their fingerprints.

However, that didn't help him.

> Fingerprints are generally attached to something else that leaves impressions on whatever it touches. That, of course, being a hand. While police found no fingerprint evidence, what they did find were several prominent palm prints with anatomically incorrect blanks where the fingerprints should be. This would end up being vitally important a few weeks later when Phillips was arrested. Shockingly, it seems that a person with no fingerprints sticks out like a non-fingerprinted sore thumb when it comes time to book people into jail. It's not like there are millions of fingerprintless people walking around out there. It was pretty much just Phillips. So his printless fingers were just as damning as a matching set of prints would have been.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure i'd count cracked as a great source; it might be better to link directly to the original encyclopedia of crime reference.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an article (LANG=DE)](http://www.scinexx.de/wissen-aktuell-13761-2011-08-09.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20scinexx%20%28scinexx%20%7C%20Das%20Wissensmagazin%29), talking about the dependency of fingerprints from a single gene, cited in the `American Journal of Human Genetics, 2011; DOI: 10.1016/j.ajhg.2011.07.004`. They don't talk about manipulation of fingerprints, but of the mutation, they observed in whole families (there are only 4 families known, with multiple people affected from the deviation), which they investigated further, to find out, that a single modification is responsible, to make the fingerprint vanish. (But from the beginning - not modifying a living person or adult).

Fingerprints are available after 24 weeks of pregnancy, and don't change significantly later.

Whether it will be possible, to provoke this in near future, isn't discussed.